# Go Colly how to find requested element?

Tags: go, web-scraping, go-colly

I'm trying to get specific table to loop through its content using colly but table its not being recognized, here's what I have so far.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    
    "github.com/gocolly/colly"
)

func main() {
    c := colly.NewCollector(
        colly.AllowedDomains("wikipedia.org", "en.wikipedia.org"),
    )
    
    links := make([]string, 0)

    c.OnHTML("div.mw-parser-output", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        
        e.ForEach("table.wikitable.sortable.jquery-tablesorter > tbody > tr", func(_ int, elem *colly.HTMLElement) {
            fmt.Println(elem.ChildAttr("a[href]", "href"))
            links = append(links, elem.ChildAttr("a[href]", "href"))
        })
    })
    
    c.OnRequest(func(r *colly.Request) {
        fmt.Println("Visiting", r.URL.String())
    })

    c.Visit("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_population")
    fmt.Println("Found urls for", len(links), "countries.")
}
```

I need to loop thought all of the tr elements in the the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out name of the class is actually `wikitable.sortable` even though in chrome console is shown as `wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter`. I dont know why the names are different like this but it solved the problem for me.